# Counting inversion in array using merge sort not giving correct result

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, mergesort

I have implemented program to count inversion in array using  merge sort. Program is same as merge sort with slight change for inversion counting .

```
public class HMergeSortVer1 {

    public int inversions;

    public void msort(int [] A,int p, int r){
        if(p<r){
            int q=(int) Math.floor((r+p)/2);
        //  System.out.println("q--"+q);
            msort(A, p, q);
            msort(A, q+1, r);
            merge(A,p,q,r);
        }

    }

    private void merge(int [] A,int p,int q,int r){
        //System.out.println("In the merge");
        int n1=q-p+1; // number of elements in left array
        int n2=(r-q);
        int[] L=new int[n1+1];
        int[] R=new int[n2+1];
        for(int i=0;i<n1;i++){
            L[i]=A[p+i];
        }
        for(int j=0;j<n2;j++){
            R[j]=A[q+j+1];
        }
        L[n1]=Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        R[n2]=Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        int i=0;
        int j=0;
        for(int k=p;k<(r+1);k++){
            if(L[i]<= R[j]){                
                A[k]=L[i];
                i=i+1;
            }
            else {
                A[k]=R[j];
                j=j+1;
                int numOFElements=n1-i; 
                inversions=inversions+numOFElements; // this counts inversion
            }
        }
    }

}
```

It is working for some cases, but in other cases it gives wrong output. Kindly let me know if I am missing something.

Comment: The `**` formatting will not work for code, by the way.

Comment: A test case where the inversions are counted incorrectly would be helpful.

Comment: i didn't see anything wrong with the merge sort. i try it.

Comment: It would be more readable if you change the names of your variables to `start` / `left`, `end` / `right`, `mid`, etc. It may be better to return `inversions` rather than have it be a global (do you reset it?).

Answer (score 0):

This is the same implementation of Cormen book. But in the book it assumes the array are 1-indexed. Probably is this. Try to change your code considering you have 0-indexed arrays.

If it is 0-indexed so you n1 varible should be egual to q-p

Answer (score 0):

The issue is you are using "inversions" as "int" data type therefore it overflows for very large input. Use "long" instead & it should work fine.